# Perfect rotation around centre point in Actionscript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, object, rotation, center

I was trying to make a object rotate around its centre point,
but I noticed that the object was moving away from its original point during rotation.
Here it's my code:

```
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.display.Shape;


var rectangle:Shape = new Shape  ;
var timer:Timer = new Timer(1,360);

rectangle.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
rectangle.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100,100);
rectangle.graphics.endFill();
rectangle.x = 200;
rectangle.y = 200;
addChild(rectangle);

timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,rotateNOW);
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE,rotationDone);

function rotateNOW(e:TimerEvent)
{
    var matrix:Matrix = rectangle.transform.matrix;
    var rect:Rectangle = rectangle.getBounds(rectangle.parent);
    matrix.translate(- (rect.left + (rect.width/2)), - (rect.top + (rect.height/2)));
    matrix.rotate((1/180)*Math.PI);
    matrix.translate(rect.left + (rect.width / 2), rect.top + (rect.height / 2));
    rectangle.transform.matrix = matrix;
}
function rotationDone(e:TimerEvent)
{
    timer.reset();
    timer.start();
    trace("x:",rectangle.x,"y:",rectangle.y); //to observe the x y changes

}

timer.start();
```

Is there any way to rotate without the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hm, I suspect maybe the subtle shifting is cased by a loss of precision?

Since you're getting the matrix from the rectangle, adjusting it, then reapplying it over and over, there might be bits of precision loss adding up throughout causing the shift.

If I set the rotation to a number like 90 degrees (something resulting in no decimals?) the shift goes away.

Not sure how you can fix this if you insist on doing the rotation this way (by reading the matrix off the display object, transforming it, then reapplying it)... but there are other ways to rotate a shape. The easiest way I can think of is to use the DisplayObject's rotation property.

Example of this is below (changed from your code):

```
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.display.Shape;

var rectangle:Shape = new Shape();
var timer:Timer = new Timer(1,360);

rectangle.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
// shifted the x and y by half negative width and height so 0, 0 is at the center
rectangle.graphics.drawRect(-50, -50, 100, 100);
rectangle.graphics.endFill();
rectangle.x = 200;
rectangle.y = 200;
addChild(rectangle);

timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,rotateNOW);
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE,rotationDone);

function rotateNOW(e:TimerEvent):void {
    rectangle.rotation++;
}

function rotationDone(e:TimerEvent):void {
    timer.reset();
    timer.start();
    trace("x:",rectangle.x,"y:",rectangle.y); //to observe the x y changes
}

timer.start();
```

Comment: I solved this by a similar way - using another container.Thank you!